# Android - How to update a custom list item single component in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have custom list item with 5 `textviews` and 1 `progressbar` in a `recyclerview`.

I want to update one `Progressbar` of a listItem in every second.

To achieve this I use  `Runnable` and `Handler`, I have used

```
progressHandler.postDelayed( runnable ,1000);
```

In `run` method of runnable I have update the listItem and set in `RecyclerView.Adapter` subclass

```
this.mAdapter.refresh(position, listInfo);
```

Refresh method is as follows in adapter

```
public void refresh(int position, ListInfo item){
        this.filteredData.set(position, item);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

This works and update the custom listItem every second.

**But the problem is, it also updates the 5 text views in ListItem and the list item update flicks**

Is there any way to update only the Progressbar in the listItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of updating the entire list item, what you can do is outside the adapter class instead of

```
this.mAdapter.refresh(position, listInfo);
```

Use this

```
View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(position - linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition());// linearLayoutManager is recyclerview's layout manager
                    if (view != null) {
                        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
                        progressBar.postDelayed( runnable ,1000);
                    }
```

Comment: @Pokhriyal Thanks,
But after implementing this if i scroll the list, progressbar update stops.
So i have to mix up with both ProgressBar and Handler.